# Javascript go back only working with certain sites

Tags: javascript, html, back

I got this html file which is simply supposed to bring the user one site back (outsourced it after it didn't work where it was supposed to).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function goBack() {
                history.back();
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="history.back()">
    </body>
</html>
```

After some playing around with it I noticed that it actually works just not where I tested it. When I visit e.g. amazon.com and then click on my bookmark to this html-file I get back to amazon.com.
When visiting e.g. stackoverflow.com and then clicking my bookmark I stay at my back.html and am not moved back.

Any idea to what's the cause of this?

Comment: Takes me back alright.

Comment: Use your browser's back button?

Comment: If you really just want a bookmark doing that, save this as a bookmark `javascript:history.back()`. Or, you know, use your back button.

Comment: you can also use `document.referrer` to know where a user is coming from and redirect to this page

Comment: My original thought on it was this: I open a link which calls a perl-script. after that script ran I want to be back where I started. Problem is that I can and do call this script from two different files (e.g. index.php and file.php). I am able to do this for either one of those but what I need is to simply go back as I tried above so I'll get to the page I was before.
Right now this is the line that gets me back to index.php
`print "<html><head><meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0; URL=/cgi-bin/index.php\"></head></html>";`

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [Window.history article on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/history) to find some of the nuances of `window.history`. The HTML5 History API gave developers some new toys to play with in regards to [modifying/tweaking the user's history](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history).

If you're visiting a site that doesn't work as expected, there's a good chance that there's JS running on that site that's altering your browser history.